# How to change name of attribute in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I do have a model named:

```
Post  with attributes id | name | extra_income
```

When I get data from request `extra_income`  is being send as `extra_pay`
so when I do `Post::create(request()->all());`  `extra_income` is null because of obvious reasons name no match.

Question is there any way to modify `extra_income` attribute on Post model so I could map it to `extra_pay`

Comment: which version are you playing with?

Comment: Laravel 5.6.0   . @Chay22

Comment: When released Laravel 5.6!!!???

Comment: @HirenGohel it will be released on january 2018 but my case its a bit scientific purposes ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator). And don't forget to append it in `$fillable` property since you're going to use `create`.

```
class Post
{
    protected $fillable = [
        // ...
        'extra_pay',
    ];

    public function setExtraPayAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attribute['extra_income'] = $value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have `extra_pay` in a form and `extra_income` in the `posts` table. The best way to handle this is to change the name of the element in form to `extra_income`.

Or, you could do this:

```
$data = request()->all();
$data['extra_income'] = $data['extra_pay'];
Post::create($data);
```

Or:

```
Post::create(request()->all() + ['extra_income' => request('extra_pay')]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the time, but I already know that solution! Problem is I do have multiple attributes mapped to different names from the front! I only simplified my question. So I thought there should be a better way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on 3 places

- Change in in your form which is the best choice.
- Change it in the incoming request with a merge `$request->merge(['extra_income' => $request->extra_pay]);`
- Or change it in the Post::create method, by setting all of the values manually.